# Running HTTPS service on port 443

Tags: tls, openssl, router, ports

According to the [Alexa Skills Documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/testing-an-alexa-skill), I will get an unexpected communication issue if

```
The endpoint is not configured to accept traffic over port 443.
```

I'm trying to do this with my home router. Does this mean I need to change the port of my home router off of 443 to something else, and then launch an https webserver on port 443?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running the service from your home then it will need to listen on port 443.  You will need to open this port on your allowed incoming traffic of your router.